# botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I try to use Amazon AWS DynamoDB in connection with python. For first I go trough this guide by amazon:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.01.html

Then I run Amazons code I get the error:
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

The credentials I have are at "~/.aws/credentials" and they look like this:

```
[profile-name]
aws_access_key_id=XXXX
aws_secret_access_key=YYYYYYY
```

I also tried to set up a condign file that includes

```
[profile profile-name]
aws_access_key_id=XXXX
aws_secret_access_key=YYYYYYY
```

In my IntelliJ application everything works fine with this credentials. Its just now with PyCharm.

Also I set up this logger, but the information do not helps me a lot:

```
boto3.set_stream_logger('botocore', level='DEBUG')
```

The Debug Information was:

```
2016-05-04 11:58:18,162 botocore.credentials [DEBUG] Skipping environment variable credential check because profile name was explicitly set.
2016-05-04 11:58:18,162 botocore.credentials [DEBUG] Looking for credentials via: env
2016-05-04 11:58:18,162 botocore.credentials [DEBUG] Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2016-05-04 11:58:18,162 botocore.credentials [DEBUG] Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2016-05-04 11:58:18,163 botocore.credentials [DEBUG] Looking for credentials via: config-file
2016-05-04 11:58:18,163 botocore.credentials [DEBUG] Looking for credentials via: ec2-credentials-file
2016-05-04 11:58:18,163 botocore.credentials [DEBUG] Looking for credentials via: boto-config
2016-05-04 11:58:18,163 botocore.credentials [DEBUG] Looking for credentials via: aim-role
```

and at the end: My code (same as tutorial, just with the debugger):

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3

boto3.set_stream_logger('botocore', level='DEBUG')

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-central-1',         endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")


table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='Movies',
    KeySchema=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'year',
            'KeyType': 'HASH'  #Partition key
        },
       {
            'AttributeName': 'title',
            'KeyType': 'RANGE'  #Sort key
        }
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {
            'AttributeName': 'year',
            'AttributeType': 'N'
        },
        {
            'AttributeName': 'title',
            'AttributeType': 'S'
        },

     ],
     ProvisionedThroughput={
        'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
        'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
    }
)

print("Table status:", table.table_status)
```

EDIT: If I change in my credentials the [profile-name] part du [default] I get an Connection Error.

Comment: I guess you have to set it to `default` instead of `profile-name`.
Do you have dynamodb running on you local system?

Comment: @JanZeiseweis If I change it to default I get an Connection Error.
No, dynamodb is just running on was, not on my local system.

Comment: In the prerequisites of the tutorial, you're going through, the first point is:
`Download and run DynamoDB on your computer. For more information, see Download and Run DynamoDB. `.
If you want to run it on aws, you can (as Sonius already pointed out) omit the endpoint_url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to take endpoint_url out of your code. Dont know why, but worked for me :)